# Angular Ionic3 app pagination with this.navCtrl.push link

Tags: javascript, angular, pagination, ionic3

I have a problem with pagination, i want to make a push to some pages with the same instruction. This is the instruction:

`gotoCollection(idCollection){
    this.navCtrl.push(idCollection + 'Page'); }`

Depending of the CollectionId parameter the push go to one page or another, but the problem is that if i put in push directly the name, for example **testPage** it works but if i contruct testPage like idCollection+'Page' it doesn't work.

It's because one is testPage and the other 'testPage'?

That's my template code:

```
 <ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col *ngFor="let collection of collections" col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2>
        <img (click)="gotoCollection(collection.id)" class="card-size" [src]="collection.url">     
        <p><strong>The collection ID is: {{collection.id}}</strong></p>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you show what idCollection has?

Comment: Yes sure Santiago, sorry

This is the template call:
```
   <ion-content padding>
     <ion-grid>
       <ion-row>
      <ion-col *ngFor="let collection of collections" col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2>
        <img (click)="gotoCollection(collection.id)" class="card-size" [src]="collection.url">     
        <p><strong>El id de la colección: {{collection.id}}</strong></p>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: it looks ok, just depends on what collection.id has. do you have all of those pages created for each id in the collection?

Comment: Yes, well only two at that moment but it fails on the first case not recognizing the name, but the name is seems correct.

Comment: when you did the testPage, did you write 'testPage' or testPage ?

Comment: When it works is testPage and i think that when i create it with idCollections is 'testPage'. I think that this is the point but i don't know how to construct it without '' .

Comment: yeah, that is the issue. You have 2 options.. have logic that says something like if id == 1 then this.navCtrl.push(1Page) else if (id = 2) etc ... in which case you need to import all of your pages beforehand. The other option is to use Lazy Loading, and there you can use strings to open the page.

Comment: Mmm, i think it's better Lazy Loading isn't it? If i want Lazy Loading what i need to do?

Comment: yes, that is better. Here is an example app that uses it from the creators of ionic https://github.com/mhartington/lazyLoad2-components/

Comment: Ok, thanks Santiago, i'm gonna try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options.. have logic that says something like if id == 1 then this.navCtrl.push(1Page) else if (id = 2) etc ... in which case you need to import all of your pages beforehand. The other option is to use Lazy Loading, and there you can use strings to open the page.

Here is an example of Lazy Loading app that uses it from the creators of ionic github.com/mhartington/lazyLoad2-components.